# Image Dragging through LinearLayout in android

Tags: android

Please i want to dragging Image which placed in main.xml as ImageView  so please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no built-in support for drag in drop in Android versions prior to Gingerbread (3.0) so if you targeting another android versions you'll have to implement it on your own for an example you can see Launcher application at android source code repository [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=summary)